# Adding columns based on unrelated condition in R Studio

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have an existing DF called **Health**

I need to make a new column called "Stage of Life" with the following condition-

If age is more than 37 then they are "older". If age is less than "37" then it will be labeled "Younger".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subsetting a vector; avoid the slow `ifelse` here, it's a bad habit! Instead, do a check `Age > 37` which gives boolean (TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, ...), if you add  `+ 1L` it gets converted to integer (2, 1, 2, ...) with which you can subset `c('younger', 'older')` and get 'younger', 'older', 'younger', ....

```
dat$Stage_of_life <- c('younger', 'older')[(dat$Age > 37) + 1L]
dat
#  Sex Diagnosis      Educ Age Stage_of_life
# 1   F    Cancer   College  35       younger
# 2   M  Diabetes Highscool  45         older
# 3   M     Lupus    Colege  36       younger
# 4   F    Cancer    Colege  50         older
# 5   M  Diabetes Highscool  20       younger
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Sex = c("F", "M", "M", "F", "M"), Diagnosis = c("Cancer", 
"Diabetes", "Lupus", "Cancer", "Diabetes"), Educ = c("College", 
"Highscool", "Colege", "Colege", "Highscool"), Age = c(35, 45, 
36, 50, 20), Stage_of_life = c("younger", "older", "younger", 
"older", "younger")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Don't you think it is better to do use `dplyr::if_else` or `data.table::fifelse`, both of which are faster and more improved than the base version, for readability's sake?

Comment: @diomedesdata No.

Comment: Could you please explain why? Genuine question :)

Comment: @diomedesdata Because `ifelse`s aren't necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to create a new variable in R.

Here is one way that would work (keeping your name as is)

```
Health$`Stage of life` <- ifelse(Age < 37, "Younger", "Older")
```

But there are are lots of others.